# Will HTA (HTML Application) still be a thing after windows 10 is launched?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-10-preview, microsoft-edge

HTAs rely on Internet Explorer. IE is about to get replaced, so will hta files also die??

Comment: AFAIR IE won't be removed, it just won't be the default browser.

Comment: This was asked at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975195/will-microsoft-edge-and-windows-10-support-hta) a few days ago, but I'm not sure how authoritative or permanent the answer is.

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows 10 will still include the Internet Explorer 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx) for compatibility reasons to legacy HTA Applications.

[image]

So you're safe and everything will still work.